# EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-leaks, uibutton

For the last two releases, we received so many crashes related to CFNetwork and EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS. So we have tried to figure out the issue and we have enabled the NSZombie and validate through debug memory graph. we are getting a purple warning over the below images.

[image]

[image]

Is there any issue when creating a button programmatically like the below images and give me some pointers for another image issue also.

```
class CustomButton{

    var didTab: (() -> Void)?


    private let button  :UIButton
    init(text: String,fontSize: CGFloat) {
        button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont (name: "MuseoSans-500", size: fontSize)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(_didTabButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func setImage(_ image: UIImage?) -> Self{
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        return self
    }

    func setTitleColor(_ color:UIColor, _ state: UIControl.State)-> Self{
        button.setTitleColor(color, for: state)
        return self
    }
    func addTarget(target: Any?, action: Selector, fors:  UIControl.Event) -> Self{
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: fors)
        return self
    }

    func isHidden(bool: Bool)-> Self{
        button.isHidden = bool
        return self
    }

    func changeColor(color:UIColor) -> Self{
        button.backgroundColor = color
        return self
    }

    func buildUI() -> UIButton{
        return button
    }

    @objc
    private func _didTabButton() {
        didTab?()
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
let notificationButton = CustomButton(text: "", fontSize: 20)
    .setImage(UIImage(named:"notification"))
    .addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(notificationList), fors: .touchUpInside)
    .buildUI()


func setUpView(){
    view.addSubview(notificationButton)
}
func setUpConstrainsts(){
    //notificationButton
    notificationButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    notificationButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    notificationButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    notificationButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

}

Comment: You are not providing any frame for your button

Comment: We have added constraints programmatically and the buttons is working as expected.